# How to check a variable is a real object or just a reference to an object

Tags: javascript

Considering:

```
A = {};
A.test = 123;
B = A;
C = {};
for (key in A) C[key] = A[key]; // a crude clone.
```

In this example, B is a reference to A, C is a deep-copy of A.

I know I can check them by `A === B` and `A === C`

But if I don't have an `A`, can I distinguish "B" and "C" without knowing "A" ?

Comment: No. **JavaScript does *not* use "references" to objects**. An object is just another value (objects are actually a subset values). Nothing special. Java uses *different* terminology; JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: @inhan Yes. In the [ECMAScript reference](http://es5.github.com) (!), "reference" is used to talk about a *reference to a property or variable*, such as `x` in `del x` or `x = ..`. There is no other meaning of the term given in the ECMAScript specification and using it in JavaScript is just bringing in baggage from other languages.

Comment: @pst So how can `A = {}; B = A; B.foo='bar'; console.log(A.foo)` return **bar** unless B is a reference here?

Comment: @inhan Why would it *not*? An object is itself. Modifying that object well, modifies that object. Since both A and B evaluate to the same object then there is no contradiction. (An assignment, or passing an object, does *not* copy/clone/duplicate that object.)

Comment: @pst Thank you . It's a little hard for me to change C/C++ concepts to JavaScript. I'm still trying to learn this.

Comment: @PG_ You're welcome. I look at a few C++ questions from time to time .. and usually leave utterly confused :( JavaScript does not have any "copy constructor" magic, but this is what I'm used to.

Comment: @pst Doesn't "not copying/cloning/duplicating" at the phase of assigning actually mean creating a reference, or am I confusing the term?

Comment: BTW, How could I implement a complex tree without using pointers in JS? Any keyword is appreciated.

Comment: @inhan Not at the JavaScript language level. An *implementation* will most definitely store a "pointer" as the value - and pass that "pointer" by value - so that it can evaluate to the same object. But the beauty is this isn't exposed in JavaScript. Simply sit back and deal with objects (which are just a subset of all values) as first-class citizens.

Comment: (Some languages like Java have the JLS which very explicitly talk about "references to objects"; but this is entirely forgone in the ECMAScript specification which merely focus on behavior.)

Comment: @pst thanks for the info. I didn't know how references work **internally** in JS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "real object" in Javascript. A is *also* a reference.

If you examine `B === C` you will be able to find that they are separate objects but you won't be able to tell which one is the "original".

Comment: Thank you. I know all of them are not real. I'm sorry for my poor English. I don't know how to say "A" is an object defined by myself, not just a reference to something others I defined before. In my example, "A" will be modified if you change the value of "B" but "C" won't. I'm looking for a solution to implement a tree structure which can be done by pointers in C/C++. I've faced a problem: When I want to modify something, I don't know I'm modifying "a reference to my object (correct)" or "a clone to my object (wrong, the modification won't be applied to my object)".

Comment: Nit to keep in mind: `B === C` only works for *objects*, not all *values* (of which objects are a subset).

Comment: @PG_: Without seeing what you are trying to do with more detail its going to be hard to answer well. there probably is a simpler way to solve your problem that doesn't need to check if something is a clone or not. How is your tree structure built? Why do you clone objects sometimes and sometimes don't? (Couldn't you just always clone or never clone?). All I know is that in Javascript you only have object "pointers", and don't have "stack allocated objects".

Comment: @missingno Thanks. You're right. I need to change my implement method. But I wonder that if there's an easy way to fix it in few lines or not.

Answer (score 1):

A variable in javascript never IS an object but holds a reference to an object.  You can think of javascript as containing a bunch of objects and any assignment of that object to a variable is just putting a reference into the variable.  So, there is no difference between the first variable to hold a reference to the object and the last one that you assigned it to.

```
var x = {a: 1};
var y = x;
y.b = 2;
```

There is no difference between `y` and `x` at this point - they both contain references to the same object.

If you make a crude clone like you did, then it's a completely different object with no further connection to the original.  Changes to the clone won't affect the original.